# Treepanel with scrollbar in ExtJS 6

Tags: javascript, extjs

It seems like `ExtJs 6` looks good and fast, because there are still myriads of bugs. For example, I cannot add a vertical scrollbar to the treepanel. As a result when there are too many nodes, I'm unable to scroll through all of them. This is what I tried:

```
{
    xtype: "treepanel",
    scrollable: true, // <-- Does not work!
    autoScroll: true, // <-- Does not work!
    ....
```

I wonder why such primitive things stopped working in modern `ExtJs`. I hope there is some magic mantra that can fix it.

Comment: You've posted a few questions with one or 2 lines of code. How do you expect anybody can help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the container's layout config. 
Try this:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: "treepanel",
        scrollable: true
    }]
}
```

Comment: You're right that it does depend on how any containers are laid out, but from the question you can't really answer this because it doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Obviously, it is overnesting. What I have, is a simplest region with a toolbar and treepanel.

Comment: It's overnesting, but it works =).